# I cannot modify the highlighted color of the potree

Tags: javascript, potree

I use BoxVolume in Potree to obtain data on points in the box, and it is always difficult to modify the color of the box highlight function. The highlighted color can be modified in the shade of the Potree source code, but it is always black through uniform modification. Is there a better solution

I modified the source code of the potree to load the RBG color of the highlighted vColor, and directly modified it to change the color. However, the uniform modification failed

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Perhaps ask them at [potree](https://github.com/potree/potree/issues)